# How do I assign a javascript variable (on a page) with a value returned by php function (in functions.php) in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, variables

I have a php function which simply returns a value, I want to assign that value to a variable in my javascript code in my frontend page.

email_data() function in functions.php:

```
function email_data()           
{

$a = 0;

$form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if ( $form_to_DB ) 

  $formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();

$type = implode(',', $formData['type']);
$type = $type . ' ' . $formData['type-other'];
$place = implode(',', $formData['place']);
$place = $place . ' ' . $formData['place-other'];
$Postcode = $formData['Postcode'];
$date = $formData['date'];
$location_long = $formData['cf7-location-lng'];
$location_lat = $formData['cf7-location-lat']; 
$location_litter = $formData['cf7-location-url']; 
$location_litter = $formData['location-340'];
$comment = $formData['comment'];

if ($formData != null)
{
    echo "Hi there! I want to report illegal dumping which consists of $type at $place area. The coordinates of the dumping are Lat: $location_lat, Long: $location_long.";

}
else
{

    echo "Please fill the above form first!"
}
return $a;
}
```

I have some html and javascript code on one of my pages which I am using to display a form. Now, I want the variable returned by the php code to be saved in a JS variable. I have tried doing so many things but nothing works out, I am a newbie in WordPress dev sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). It allows you to pass PHP variables to the browser, where your javascript can then read.